# Electronic store security

Tags: physical, user-tracking, security-theater, tracking, business-logic-attack

Iam not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. I would like to know what security features an electronic store should have besides the general alarm system monitored by a security company?

Its not a big electronic store but not small, should i consider things like a storeroom, safe or vault, although i do think a vault is too much for a the store. Would the safety room (vault,safe or store room) be protected by separate alarm and if so what would it be like, a gsm based unit? Note the safety room is for the electronics not on display.

Should i consider tracking devices and if so how would the work with the electronics such as cameras,laptops and cellphones etc.

Thanks guys

Comment: This is about **information** security here which means your question is off-topic. And, the tags you gave do not fit the question you ask. But apart from this: the security measures  you need depend on the risk you actually have which depends on various factors, like for example your  neighborhood, the country you live, its economic state, how people can trust each other or the value of the things you sell. The best is probably to look at what similar established stores in your neighborhood do.